# libmysqlclient_18 not found

Tags: c++, mysql, database, linux, eclipse

I'm trying to connect to mysql with C++ and the MySQLConnector, but I'm getting "undefined reference" errors everytime I make calls to the connector.

example:

/usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_execute@libmysqlclient_18'

My OS is Ubuntu 13.04 VM, I'm using Eclipse CDT and I installed the packages:

```
sudo apt-get mysql-client
sudo apt-get mysql-server
sudo apt-get mysql-client
sudo apt-get libmysqlclient-dev
```

I'm wondering that the libs (libmysqlclient,..) are in the folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
and not in /user/local/mysql/lib like often found on the net. Does this make any difference?

I also downloaded the C++ Connector (binaries) from Oracle and copied the lib directory to /usr/lib and the include directory to /usr/include, but still I'm gettind the undefined reference errors.
I configured Eclipse in a way that I get this compile command:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread -o "Proj"  ./Client.o -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlclient -lz -lm -ldl
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be the version of mysql client you have installed is not compatible with the libraries from oracle for the C++ connector.

Comment: What would be the right way to get 2 compatible versions? I installed the packages above and downloaded the connector for Debian Linux (doesn't work with the Linux Generic either) 'Debian Linux 6.0 (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive' from 'http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/'. The undefined references should be in libmysqlclient_18 i think - the libmysqlclient.so.8.0.0 file is in the folder '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'

Comment: If you look at that site, it suggests building from source to maintain compatibility.  Most likely MySQL on your ubuntu install is newer than that which came with Debian 6.  Ubuntu is often "ahead" of Debian on package versions. You can either look for a package in ubuntu for that library or select "Source" from the download menu and build it on your system against the MySQL release you're using.